# Data retrieved from API using Postman different than when using C# program

Tags: c#, postman, dotnet-httpclient

Data which I retrieved from a sigfox API using postman is different than the data which I got when using C# program using http client.

The API contains query parameters such as:

- limit=(a number) -- number which limits the number of messages I can receive (doesn't affect the problem)

and

- before = (unix time)
- since= (unix time)
  which is the time parameters.

In postman, the data I received follows the time parameter meaning data received is before set timing and since set timing.

Api link(with fake info):
https://backend.sigfox.com/api/devicetypes/devicetpes-id(filler)/messages?limit=100&before=1568186400&since=1568185800

This is for the download section of the data:

```
public static class DownloadData
{
    private static string UrlParameters="?limit=100&before=&since=";
    public static void GetfromAPI(string deviceId, long beforeTime, long sinceTime)
    {
        var apiResponse = new Models.Datas();
        var baseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiBaseUrl"];
        var username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiUserName"];
        var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiPassword"];
        var mediatype = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MediaType"];
        var finalUrl = string.Format(baseUrl, deviceId, beforeTime, sinceTime);
        using (var client = new ApiClient(finalUrl, username, password, mediatype))
        {
            //apiResponse = client.GetAsyncMessage<Models.Datas>(UrlParameters).Result;
            apiResponse = client.GetAsyncMessage<Models.Datas>(UrlParameters).Result;
            InsertToDatabase(FormatData(apiResponse.Data)); //apiresponse.data is holding the data

        }
    }
```

http client

```
public class ApiClient : IDisposable
{
    private HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly string _baseurl;
    private readonly string _username;
    private readonly string _password;
    private readonly string _mediatype;


    public ApiClient(string baseurl, string username, string password , string mediatype)
    {
        _baseurl = baseurl;
        _username = username;
        _password = password;
        _mediatype = mediatype;
    }

    public async Task<TResult> GetAsyncMessage<TResult>(string url) where TResult : class, new()

    {
        var strResponse = await GetAsyncMessage(url);



        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(strResponse, new JsonSerializerSettings ///str respons holding the string 
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        });
    }

    private async Task<string> GetAsyncMessage(string url)
    {
        CheckHttpClientConnection();

        using (var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


        }
    }
```

httpclientwith basic auth

```
private void CreateHttpClient()
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseurl) };
        byte[] cred = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_username + ":" + _password);
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(cred));
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(_mediatype));
    }
```

a FUNCTION in another file which runs the top code

```
DownloadData.GetfromAPI("devicetypesid filler",Common.BCurrenttimetoUnix(), Common.SCurrenttimetoUnix());

the common.bcurrentimetounix etc is taking the value from the function as the before and since query parameters.
```

So data i got in postman follows the query parameter. meaning that data i got is in the before and since timing span.

example:

before :4.50pm since 4.40pm is the timing set for params.

Data retrieved is 1st data = 4.49pm,  100th data= 4.41pm.

However in my C# program it does not even follow the parameter. data retrieved exceed both since and before timing.

EDIT #1. Images

[image]

**EDIT #2**

BASEURL :

```
<add key="ApiBaseUrl" value="https://api.sigfox.com/v2/device-types/{0}/messages" />
```

**Edit #3**

Working with this as baseurl:
Debugging screenshots :

[image]

```
  <add key="ApiBaseUrl"  value="https://api.sigfox.com/v2/device-types/{0}/messages?limit=100&amp;before={1}&amp;since={2}" />
```

**Edit #4**

This code is working.

```
        public static void GetfromAPI(string deviceId, long beforeTime, long sinceTime)
        {
            var apiResponse = new Models.Datas();
            var baseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiBaseUrl"];
            var username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiUserName"];
            var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiPassword"];
            var mediatype = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MediaType"];
            var urlparam = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiParam"];
                
            var finalurl = string.Format(baseUrl, deviceId);
            var urlParam = $"?limit=100&before={beforeTime}&since={sinceTime}";

            using (var client = new ApiClient(finalurl, username, password, mediatype))
            {
                //apiResponse = client.GetAsyncMessage<Models.Datas>(UrlParameters).Result;
                apiResponse = client.GetAsyncMessage<Models.Datas>(urlParam).Result;
                InsertToDatabase(FormatData(apiResponse.Data)); //apiresponse.data is holding the data

            }
```

Comment: Have you used Fiddler or Burp to compare the two requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your `UrlParameters` variable without values for `before` or `since`:-

```
private static string UrlParameters="?limit=100&before=&since=";
```

And you are not updating that before you send it; where you set `finalUrl`, your `string.Format` doesn't reference `UrlParameters`; hence you are gettings values outside your specified `beforeTime` and `afterTime`.

It's not clear what ApiClient you are using, however, here is an example using the basic `WebClient`:-

```
var baseUrl = "https://backend.sigfox.com/api/devicetypes";
var deviceId = "12345";
var before = 1568186400;
var since = 1568185800;

var url = $@"{baseUrl}/{deviceId}/messages?limit=100&before={before}&since={since}";

var json = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url);
```

**EDIT**

Try updating your `GetfromAPI` method like this (I've fixed how `finalUrl` is constructed, and pass it, instead of `UrlParameters` to your `GetAsyncMessage` method and I pass `baseUrl` instead of `finalUrl` to your `ApiClient` constructor):-

```
public static class DownloadData
{
    public static void GetfromAPI(string deviceId, long beforeTime, long sinceTime)
    {
        var apiResponse = new Models.Datas();
        var baseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiBaseUrl"];
        var username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiUserName"];
        var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiPassword"];
        var mediatype = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MediaType"];

        var finalUrl = $"api/devicetypes/{deviceId}/messages?limit=100&before={beforeTime}&since={sinceTime}";

        using (var client = new ApiClient(baseUrl, username, password, mediatype))
        {
            apiResponse = client.GetAsyncMessage<Models.Datas>(finalUrl).Result;
            InsertToDatabase(FormatData(apiResponse.Data)); //apiresponse.data is holding the data
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: You may need to fiddle with `finalUrl` depending on what your `baseUrl` is set to (I can't see that here); the idea is to check that `url` value just before you pass it to `HttpClient` so you can confirm what it's trying to fetch.

Comment: hey there , there is a functions which fills the url parameters look at the last code . its is with reference to the first code in the post

Comment: I can see that `UrlParameters` gets passed to `GetAsyncMessage<TResult>(url)`, but neither that method, nor `GetAsyncMessage(url)` alter the `url` parameter before it is sent? Check the value of `url` in `GetAsyncMessage(url)` just before you call the `HttpClient`

Comment: hey there ive updated the post  with a link containing screenshots do take a look

Comment: Right, so that confirms what I'm saying... the `UrlParameters` variable is never updated, and you can see (with your debug) that it's being passed through to the server without values for `before` or `since`; that is why you are getting those results. You need to fix how you're building that string *before* you pass it to the `GetAsyncMessage` method.

Comment: i have updated the post with using a working url. any idea how i can do it like how i did it originally?

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer; I edited your code to fix the problem.

Comment: @LonelyBat any luck?

Comment: im still using the edit #3 which is working in terms of the data fetch. I am trying to find a way to do it similar to my original code.

Comment: hey there ive managed to make it work with ur help. Thank you . ill mark it as accepted answer. look at edit 4